# Access socket connection from service class within an activity

Tags: java, android, sockets, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I am trying to access a socket connection from my service class within my activity class and `emit`ting data to my server online.

```
    MyService.java

    public class MyService extends Service {

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent Intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            this.isRunning = false;
            this.backgroundThread = new Thread(myTask);
        }

        private Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                try {
                    // instantiate socket connection
                    mSocket = IO.socket(AppConstants.CHAT_SERVER_URL);

                    // establish the socket connection
                    mSocket.connect();

                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            if( !this.isRunning) {
                this.isRunning = true;
                this.backgroundThread.start();
            }

            return START_STICKY;
        }

        public Socket getSocket() {
            return mSocket;
        }
    }



    MyApplication.java

    public class MyApplication extends Application {

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            Intent background = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            startService(background);
        }
    }


    MainActivity.java

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


        Socket mSocket;
        MyService mservice;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mSocket = mservice.getSocket();

        }

        public void sendMessage(View view){
            mSocket.emit("new messaged", "this");
        }

    }
```

The above gives null error, when the `sendMessage` method within the `MainActivity` is triggered, even though the connection is established at startup.

I know very much that, I can `bind` connection and use the `ServiceConnection` class within the activity class in accessing the `mSocket` connection, however I am to use this way or a `broadcast receiver` in accessing it. Any ideas on the best away to access the socket connection without bounding service class to the activity class.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a `NullPointerException` on this:

```
mSocket = mservice.getSocket();
```

because you never assign `mservice` to anything!

Comment: I am just accessing the `getSocket()` method from the Service Class, and within that class it has already been set, anyways can you  please suggest a better way to this

Comment: you need to first set `mservice` to something before you can call `getSocket()` on it!